# Feedback on clarifying edit rejected for defacement or deviation from original intent

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, specific-edit

Could I have some feedback on this https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6443482 rejected edit please? The first rejection says "This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive." which clearly isn't the case. The next two say "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post.". Surely this rejection reason is in conflict with "This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post."?

My edit retained the intention of the post, but attempted to clarify what the user actually wanted to know, as I had to read the question several times myself to figure that out. I also removed a spurious line from the code sample given where there was a nonsensical attempt to fix the problem which was probably a copy and paste from another site.

It is clear from the comments that this had confused at least one other potential answerer. I have personally experienced and resolved the same problem as the OP; I have read through the entire question and all of the comments (did the peer reviewers do this?) and detailed all of my edits in the accompanying comment.

Clearly I am doing something wrong, though, so I would appreciate some guidance please.

Comment: When you move a paragraph, the diff shows an ugly big red rectangle where it was and an ugly big green rectangle where it moved to. The facts that you didn't say "moved a paragraph" in the description and that you changed it a little in the process didn't help either.

Comment: And then there is the code modification. While well intended, that's usually not going to fly.

Comment: ... especially not in questions. What if you fix the asker's issue accidentally?

Comment: @Jan That is useful to know, thanks.

Comment: @Bart I didn't realise editing code examples is discouraged, thanks. Makes sense I suppose, especially taking into account Jan Dvorak's subsequent comment.

Comment: *This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.* - This is not applicable to your question. It is a deviation from the author's intent, though. [This is an example of a destructive edit.](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26814397/5)

Comment: @Compass haha that is even worse than mine!

Comment: I like to see edits that focus on presentation changes, as opposed to content changes. **Fair game for edits**: fixing organization, grammar, punctuation, tags, titles. **Automatic rejects**: adding sentences that weren't there, adding adverbs/adjectives, creating thoughts, changing meaning, editing code (other than to format).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think I see what you're trying to do with that edit -- rearranging the existing text to make the question clearer. Moving the description of the error to the beginning of the question was definitely a good idea, as was removing the sign-off/thanks bit.

The final paragraph in your proposal is a problem, however; you've removed some of the OP's code and turned it into a prose description that makes the asker's understanding of the issue somewhat more *unclear* than originally.

I'd recommend re-submitting the suggestion with that line of code intact, and a rewording of the OP's sentence "a proposed solution was to add the first line (Set rs=... see above in the coding) which I did but it did not resolve the problem" as the final paragraph.

Finally, keep on editing! Most of that edit was a real improvement and work like that is very helpful to the site.

Comment: Thanks Josh, you've given me heart.

Answer (score 4):

Without looking too deeply into it, you have changed some of the code in the Question,

When you change code in a question, especially a question about an error message, you run the risk of changing or fixing the issue that's giving the OP trouble.  For some people, that's an automatic reject.