# Are purely cosmetic edits to original code frowned-upon, even if they accompany high-value non-code revisions?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, code-formatting, rejected-edits, editing-help

Having looked it up and found that code edits are almost universally rejected, I was curious what the fate of cosmetic and in-line comment edits usually were. It's obvious why edits changing the original problem code would be rejected, and understandable if an edit affects unrelated parameters, but it's a bit hazy for decorative changes.

Naturally, there's little point in making an edit just to pretty-up code, for instance:

```
def foo(self):
    self.bar = "Ashgabat"
    self.statue = "Niyazov"
    self.age = 32
    self.rotation = 293.445
```

...edited to...

```
def foo(self):
   self.bar      = "Ashgabat"
   self.statue   = "Niyazov"
   self.age      =   32
   self.rotation =  293.445
```

...since the edit has no actual meaningful content, regardless of whether it edits (without substantively altering) original code or not.

Similarly, an edit that modifies *comments* in original code, either for grammar or content, that preserves the original intent of the post (and, being a comment, does not alter how the code runs), might also be viewed as insubstantial, if it's all by itself. Consider:

```
goldenStatue.update(90.0) #make the tkmnbshi thing go round
```

...versus...

```
goldenStatue.update(90.0)  # Rotate the Turkmenbashi statue.
```

Not much value there, either.

But if these sorts of edits are made alongside other, meaningful (and otherwise permissible) edits, do they **weaken** or **enhance** the overall quality of the edit? I've read a few questions and answers on Stack Overflow's general attitude on the subject; [this one stands out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278958/feedback-on-clarifying-edit-rejected-for-defacement-or-deviation-from-original-i), and [here's another](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101583/when-is-it-appropriate-to-edit-someone-elses-code). From them, it's easy to understand what the rationale behind a `code-edit=auto-reject` mentality might be, but it's generally on the basis that the edits *effect the code in a functional, rather than entirely decorative, way*.

Can non-functioning, cosmetic code edits ride shotgun with purposeful and constructive ones?

Comment: I would reject your samples as _too minor_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - Oh, I know-- They were examples of edits that are rejectably minor on their own, like I said. My question was more about whether they were _permissible_ if they accompanied useful and significant revisions.

Comment: I don’t think it’s a matter of whether such changes strengthen or weaken your edit, but more of whether your edit including those changes strengthens the *post* significantly enough.

Comment: related/maybe dup? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266937/editing-code-formatting

Comment: @icktoofay Hmm, then should I be considering the value of _every change I make_, rather than the _maximum value of the changes I make_? Rather, should I only make changes that satisfy a certain minimal value, even if there is at least one other edit that justifies making changes at all? I feel like making minor edits is reasonable, as long as there is at least one edit in the post that's genuinely and independently worthwhile.

Comment: @Sompuperoo I actually linked that in the question text. This one is related, too: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263115/when-is-it-okay-to-edit-answers-for-code-formatting.

Comment: The first edit, aligning assignments, is _actively harmful_ - that style is heavily frowned upon and generally considered bad for a number of reasons. I'd reject it as vandalism in this case (or via "reject and edit" if it occurs along with helpful changes). The second one, improving comments, is generally helpful as it is objectively an improvement to the post. In general, cosmetic changes to code should only be accepted if they fix issues with the original formatting that make it easier to understand the code.

Comment: @l4mpi Regarding "aligning assignments": Can you link to a list of those reasons? I don't know any of them, and I'd be very interested in seeing what they are.

Comment: I wouldn't like this if somebody did it to my code, and would definitely reject this. The former is in fact more pep-8 compliant. These kind of fixes are only constructive if the original code was indented wrong.

Comment: The main arguments are maintainability, interoperability and actually readability. Imagine you follow that style and have to add a variable with a long name, or a number with 2 more digits than the old values. You'll have to change all assignments, leading to a huge diff, when all you did was introduce one variable. Interoperability is a concern when people use tabs (may be set to different widths). And readability because often the assignments have no connection whatsoever, but now appear grouped, which may make it harder to mentally parse the code. FWIW pep8 explicitly advises against it.

Comment: @simonzack True enough, but an indent change would actually modify the original code's functionality, which is straight-up wrong, right?

Comment: @l4mp1 Good points, all. Setting pep8 aside, I guess it comes down to a matter of taste (including how committed you are to maintaining offsets if a long name or awkward value spoils the day for you), which is, I should hope, not grounds for (or rather, grounds _against_) an edit. I would not have immediately thought of the tab thing, though; that's really interesting.

Comment: That number alignment style actively hurts readability, especially with just two numbers. As for tab widths, you should never use tabs for alignment anyway.

Comment: This is all great input, but it's worth reminding that the examples are samples of _revision types_ that would _accompany more significant edits_, not stand-alones that I imagine justifying an edit on their own. "The real thing" would probably be a lot more sophisticated than just a few spaces (read: non-tabbed realignment).

Anyway, it's pretty clear that realigning assignments is poor form and shouldn't be undertaken even _with_ properly-significant edits, and I've learned a lot about the why, too. Revising comments seems okay, as long as it properly preserves the original message.

Comment: N.B. that the changes made in the example are not only "Too Minor" but also go against PEP8 (the python style guide) and are therefore "wrong" in the only objective sense of the term.

Comment: I don't know if this is a valid suggestion, however perhaps a style guide can be introduced in whichever environment you are in.  If the style guide is accepted by the team. The changes you make could be considered as keeping conformity to the official style guide. Of course take my advise with salt since I've never programmed with a team, but I would love such improvements to the code base if they needed to be done. Just make sure that if you are working for a corp. that you aren't taking time out of day doing this mundane task to have something to do. Keep focus on the primary task at hand.

Comment: @AdamSmith the "Too Minor" rejection reason is gone. The new yardstick is "No improvement whatsoever."  Let the past go.

Comment: @RubberDuck ooh I had no idea! That's great :)

Comment: @AdamSmith I feel like the only "objective" sense of "wrong edits" are ones that actually _meaningfully_ damage the question itself, rather than violate a[n accepted and sensible] style guide, but that's just me. XD

Comment: Don't forget that you have the option to edit the edit, removing bad/questionable parts of the edit and keeping good ones. If editing out the questionable/bad parts leaves no good changes, then it clearly falls below the "No improvement" bar.

Comment: I would approve all of those. The primary purpose of programming languages are to make the instructions to a computer readable by and understandable to humans. Anything that improves readability is good in my book. I don't use Python so I have no issues with whitespace. The size of a diff is irrelevant, you should have good unit test coverage, and thorough regression tests for all releases. If developers must be afraid to make changes, then your development process is broken.

Comment: @Bernard I think you're mistaken here. What the hell do unit tests have to do with the readability of diffs? Either way, using your own argument, diffs should be human-readable too. It's important to be able to easily tell the differences, especially if you're accepting a patch from an external person.

Comment: If you are setting your code style to minimize the size of your diffs, then I would say that your development process is very much broken.

The issues caused by white space changes are common enough for utilities such as GNU diff to have ways of dealing with them.

Comment: @nyuszika7h
Diff readability is irrelevant. If the application performs the intended function to specifications, and the code is readable, then you are done. If you don't like your diffs then get a better diff tool but don't compromise your code because of it.

Comment: @DonCruickshank Those methods are subpar at best, and in many cases, they don't work correctly at all.

Comment: @Augusta I wrote [Avoid tabular assignment in code](http://wconrad.github.io/20150627/tabular-alignment-antipattern.html) to document three concrete reasons why tabular alignment in code can be harmful.

Answer (score 26):

I routinely reformat code to make it more readable. Often times, a question is unintelligible due to poor formatting. For example:

```
For i = 0 To 100
' lots of code here
For j = 0 To 100
'lots more code here, still at the same level of indentation
Next
Next
```

Now, pretend for a second that this example is 100 lines long and contains another nested loop or two, *all at the same level of indentation*. Go ahead and and format the code properly. It makes for a better question. In situations like this, you likely made an unanswerable question answerable, because, with proper formatting, it's almost obvious where OP went wrong.

As for your specific examples though, I consider them to be *almost* too minor, but that reject reason has gone away for good reason. It has been replaced with "No improvement whatsoever." By that standard, all we need to ask ourselves is, "Does this edit improve the quality of the question?" I think clearly the answer is "Yes". Quality has been improved. It's a good edit.

To be clear about this, as there seems to be some confusion, I am not proposing style changes for the sake of style changes. I am in support of style changes that *objectively* make the code in question more readable/understandable. On its own, without any other changes, I would reject the assignment example you posted. Any improvement is subjective and some would say it actively *harms* the post. I would, however, approve the improved comment, as it *objectively* improves the question. In either case, I would approve the edit so long as they were accompanied by other improvements.

We should not try to impose our own style on code when the OP has one already (whether we like it or not is a subjective matter). We *should* go ahead and clean up code where there is no discernible style though.

Comment: So long as the formatting doesn't change the meaning of the code (like indentation in python), and the code is difficult to read, then these edits are good

Comment: Of course @wnnmaw. Changing the *meaning* of the code is vandalism. *Clarifying* the code is a good edit. (Also note that I'm taking the general case here, not specifically Python)

Comment: TL;DR: **bikeshedding**. Long explanation: Who decides what is difficult to read? Me, you, someone else, etc? It is all personal preference and so I reject any edit that targets personal style changes even cases that you mention. It may read better for the OP if that person is used to this style. You are not, so what? That does not mean the OP cannot be or some other reader.

Comment: @lpapp First establish a style, then, the style decides. Changes to the style need to be approved by some governing body. (Whatever that may be)

Comment: @lpapp there are nuances and disagreements, but there are generally accepted style guide lines for most languages. Even when there isn't, we all know what is readable and what is not. If you don't, come post some code on Code Review and we'll show you.

Comment: I feel like we've established that what's good for one reader may not be good for another. Assignment alignment is not something you should add or remove with an edit, whether that edit adds other content or not, _save possibly for when that alignment-edit preserves/continues the existing style obviously present in the original code_.

You've both offered some very good input here, lpapp and RubberDuck, and I appreciate all of it. But I don't think you'll change eachother's minds in this comment thread. :v

Comment: @RubberDuck maybe you should change example. I would definitely consider the edit in your example too minor. Most edits I have seen where formatting was changed to improve readability were just pointless change of style (e.g. putting parenthesis on the same line of a loop vs a separate line). This is not only minor, but may also be irritating to the person who wrote the answer, who prefers a different style than the editor. That said, there are some situations where editing may indeed clarify code would be one enormous line of code, no formatting at all, etc.

Comment: @nico that's the point of my answer. There is no such thing as "Too minor" anymore. If there is *any improvement*, then it's a good edit. As for a different example, the indentation is a very real example of something I routinely fix in the VBA tag. If you have an example in mind, please feel free to edit it in. The answer is here, after all, for the benefit of the community.

Comment: @RubberDuck obviously it depends on the specific code, I feel it is very difficult to generalize. Speaking from experience, I very often saw edits that could fall in this type of category that I wouldn't consider as an improvement (and often seem to me more of an annoyance). I a medium/small proportion of cases I agree they can also be good, though this has to be judged on a case-by-case situation.

Answer (score 22):

I will regularly deny low-value edits that just move code around unless it specifically improves overall question **quality**. There's no point in aligning equals signs. But if there is a systemic formatting problem that makes the code unreadable, and you fix that and sprinkle in some equals-sign alignment for good measure, then I'll accept that no problem.

It's very clearly defined as a rejection reason: `No improvement whatsoever.`

Comment: So if it accompanies other, high-value edits, they don't detract as long as they, at worst, do no harm?

Comment: I whole heartedly disagree with that attitude @AlexeiLevenkov. And I believe the devs so as well. Otherwise, why would they have gotten rid of the "Too Minor" rejection reason. Embrace the change. "No improvement whatsoever " is a much better yardstick.

Comment: @RubberDuck "No improvement whatsoever" feels like a strange and risky leap from merely "Not significant," but I guess if that's the shorthand, it's worth knowing.

Comment: @Augusta it was announced [on the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/) and [here on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238333/256822).

Comment: This answer, please. ^

Answer (score 20):

For code-formatting, there's one guideline:

**Don't force your own preferences on anyone else.**

Which means you can make formatting consistent, and if the code does not have any consistent style, you can apply the only true one (which is *my* preferred one), but if it is consistent, leave it alone.

Does lining up equal signs make the post *more* readable?
Unlikely, though not impossible if it highlights something important. Probably just a gratuitious change which should be rejected.

Does lining up equal signs make the post *less* readable?
Unlikely, but possible.

In the end, I would probably ignore the shifted equal signs if the rest of the edit is worthwhile, though it needs to be better to overcome that deficit.

Answer (score 7):

I sometimes reformat code a little, but this mainly boils down to breaking very long lines. I make these changes, because I think it is very hard to answer a question when the code is very hard to read, and big horizontal scrollbars are a common cause for that.

On even rarer occasions, I add some indentation, but mainly when it's a big, complex nested piece of code, or its a complete mess, and preferably only when it isn't related to the cause. If the nesting caused poor readability, and that caused a bug in the code (like a statement block that wasn't closed correctly), I prefer to comment or give an answer that fixes the issue and explains that the messy code was part of the cause. In that case, fixing the code in the original question would invalidate that point. :)

Apart from that, I think you should leave code in a question as-is and don't ever change naming, casing or specific style preferences like `{` after or under `if`, as well as your example of aligning equal signs (which I think is a waste of effort anyway).

If I feel like it, I even try to answer in a similar style as OP asked, or when thinks look very messy or confusing, I try to give the answer in an improved style and sometimes make a remark like "try this, it will make your code more readable".

I don't think you should change the actual workings of the code. I've sometimes seen people silently fixing a typo in code, which turned out to be the reason behind the question. So by doing so, you make hundreds of SO-members search for a bug in a perfect piece of code. Don't do that.

And even if you don't (intentionally) change behaviour, there is always this risk, so that's why I think you should be very reticent changing code in a question (or answer, for that matter).

Comment: I think you might be *slightly* too shy about improving posts (which might include removing lots of superfluous boilerplate, or even global renaming), as this is not [codereview.SE]. Still, you are certainly right there's considerable danger involved in doing so, and it's better to leave a post as-is than risking damaging it.

Comment: I agree with most of this, but also think you're a bit too conservative.  We need to think about future visitors to the post, not just OP. Making the code in question clear can make it much easier to be sure that you're having the same problem as OP.