# Are edits that purely reformat code, based on preference, good edits?

Tags: discussion, edits, code-formatting

Start note: This question is very similar to a question that was flagged as similar. [Are purely cosmetic edits to original code frowned-upon, even if they accompany high-value non-code revisions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281156/2029983) The example is that question is *very* minor though, and I am referencing larger changes.

Editing of post to improve them is something we see very commonly, we all know this and many of us contribute to this; it's good that we do as a well formatted question will be a well received question.

The question I linked above touches on this, but I wanted to go a little further.

Let's say you have a question, that is pretty well formatted (maybe a typographical error somewhere) and includes some code (SQL in my case) below:

```
DROP TABLE USERS;

CREATE TABLE USERS(
    USERID integer not null primary key,
    USERNAME char(8),
    FIRSTNAME varchar(30),
    LASTNAME varchar(30),
    CITY varchar(30),
    STATE char(2),
    EMAIL varchar(100),
    PHONE char(14),
    LIKESPORTS bit not null default 0,
    LIKETHEATRE bit not null default 0,
    LIKECONCERTS bit not null default 0,
    LIKEJAZZ bit not null default 0,
    LIKECLASSICAL bit not null default 0,
    LIKEOPERA bit not null default 0,
    LIKEROCK bit not null default 0,
    LIKEVEGAS bit not null default 0,
    LIKEBROADWAY bit not null default 0,
    LIKEMUSICALS bit not null default 0
);

INSERT INTO USERS (USERID,USERNAME,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,CITY,STATE,EMAIL,PHONE,LIKESPORTS,LIKETHEATRE,LIKECONCERTS,LIKEJAZZ,LIKECLASSICAL,LIKEOPERA,LIKEROCK,LIKEVEGAS,LIKEBROADWAY,LIKEMUSICALS)         VALUES ('1','JSG99FHE','Rafael','Taylor','Kent','WA','Etiam.laoreet.libero@sodalesMaurisblandit.edu','(664) 602-4412','TRUE','TRUE',0,'TRUE','FALSE',0,0,'TRUE','FALSE','TRUE')
INSERT INTO USERS (USERID,USERNAME,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,CITY,STATE,EMAIL,PHONE,LIKESPORTS,LIKETHEATRE,LIKECONCERTS,LIKEJAZZ,LIKECLASSICAL,LIKEOPERA,LIKEROCK,LIKEVEGAS,LIKEBROADWAY,LIKEMUSICALS)         VALUES ('2','PGL08LJI','Vladimir','Humphrey','Murfreesboro','SK','Suspendisse.tristique@nonnisiAenean.edu','(783) 492-1886',0,0,0,'TRUE','TRUE',0,0,'TRUE','FALSE','TRUE')
```

This, in my view, is well formatted SQL. The biggest problem, in my view, is that very wide `INSERT` statements at the bottom, which means (a lot of) side scrolling to view the statement.

Would an edit, therefore, that *may* slightly change the rest of the post (maybe change a piece of text from .sql to `.sql` or Sql server management studio to SQL Management Studio) but changes the writing to this a good change?

```
DROP TABLE USERS;

CREATE TABLE USERS
(
    USERID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    USERNAME CHAR(8),
    FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(30),
    LASTNAME VARCHAR(30),
    CITY VARCHAR(30),
    STATE CHAR(2),
    EMAIL VARCHAR(100),
    PHONE CHAR(14),
    LIKESPORTS BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    LIKETHEATRE BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    LIKECONCERTS BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    LIKEJAZZ BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    LIKECLASSICAL BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    LIKEOPERA BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    LIKEROCK BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    LIKEVEGAS BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    LIKEBROADWAY BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    LIKEMUSICALS BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

INSERT INTO USERS (USERID, USERNAME, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, CITY, STATE, EMAIL, PHONE, LIKESPORTS, LIKETHEATRE, LIKECONCERTS, LIKEJAZZ, LIKECLASSICAL, LIKEOPERA, LIKEROCK, LIKEVEGAS, LIKEBROADWAY, LIKEMUSICALS)         
VALUES ('1', 'JSG99FHE', 'Rafael', 'Taylor', 'Kent', 'WA', 'Etiam.laoreet.libero@sodalesMaurisblandit.edu', '(664) 602-4412', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 0, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 0, 0, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'TRUE'),
('2', 'PGL08LJI', 'Vladimir', 'Humphrey', 'Murfreesboro', 'SK', 'Suspendisse.tristique@nonnisiAenean.edu', '(783) 492-1886', 0, 0, 0, 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 0, 0, 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'TRUE')
```

Here, everything have been capitalised; any word that could be seen as a keyword.

Capitalisation in SQL Server is purely preference for keywords. Unlike some languages (like C#) casing is not enforced unless you are using a Case Sensitive Collation, and even then things like data types are not case sensitive.

To me, this very much feels like an enforcement of preference on formatting on the OP. Personally I *do* prefer that my data types are lower case and my functions upper, but I admit, that is a **preference**.

If the edit in the prior post had been *only* to change the formatting of the SQL above, would you still give the same yes/no answer you gave before?

In this particular event I did roll the edit back, but that was also due to the underlying SQL being changed; instead of 2 `INSERT` statements, it was changed to 1, which *could* have hidden an underlying error.

I admit, that I do change the styles of code when it's poorly formatted, however, the reason is because I *own* the Redgate tools to quickly format said code and it uses *my* preferences. To make an example, there was a question I edited a few weeks ago that had SQL like this:

```
INSERT into P_BS.dbo.FI_ARAP  WITH (ROWLOCK)
       (Class, VoucherNo, VoucherCounter, VoucherDate, IsAR, IncomeOrExpense, AssociateID, AssociateName, CurrencyID, ExchangeRate, PaymentMethod, VoucherType, RecordedGuestID, IsFODeposit,
        ExpenseOrRevenueTypeID, ReservationID, CutFare, DontPostToGL, BankAccountID, CheckNo, CheckDueDate, ClearingID, BankName, CardHolderName, AccountNo, AmountPaid, Remarks, InternalRemarks,
                ExcludeInARAP, CollectorID, CardTypeID, CardTerminalID, [External],
        AccountOwner, HMSDate, HMSShiftID, POSOID, CreatedBy, CreateDate, LastModBy, LastMod, IncomingTransferVerified, AutoGenerated,
        GoldAdjustmentID, Confidential, EmployeeAdvance, Transferred, DeductedPPh, ExSourceID, ExSource, WriteOffDepartment,
      AccountIndex, BIAssetID, BIDriverID, IsPanjarUJ, BankCharges, BankChargesAccountID, BankChargesDepartment, PIN, SourceCashRefundID, PPhTypeID, EBankingMetadata, FPNo, BQID, ProjectID, Pending, DeliveryOrderID, KCPDeliveryOrderID,
        FFBContractID, SourceVoucherID, IncentiveDetailID, ExternalRef, OtherOwnerCheck, IsSODeposit, TransferDate, Jaminan, WriteOffAccountID, PVTax, PVAmountTax, ForexGainLossDepartment, ForexGainLossAccountID,
        IsPriviledge, PriviledgeCardNumber, PPhFormula, CashFlowID, PVSalesPersonID, PalmContractID, ExpMeterai, CashRate, PPhLocal, IsAnonym, AnonymName, RequireCheck, EDUHideDiscount, EDUDiscReason, BAccountType,
                PPh23ID, SettlementDescription, AdvanceAccountID, EDUReportDate, DedOtobon,
                City, Branch, Country, IBANCode, SwiftCode, SortCode, PendingCashID, PendingCashAmount, ChargeAmount,
                BranchCode, ABACode, CorrBank, CorrSwiftCode, AllowOverBudget, POTerm)
VALUES( @Class, @VoucherNo, @VoucherCounter, @VoucherDate, @IsAR, @IncomeOrExpense, @AssociateID, @AssociateName, @CurrencyID, @ExchangeRate, @PaymentMethod, @VoucherType, @RecordedGuestID, @IsFODeposit,
       @ExpenseOrRevenueTypeID, @ReservationID, @CutFare, @DontPostToGL, @BankAccountID, @CheckNo, @CheckDueDate, 0, @BankName, @CardHolderName, @AccountNo, @AmountPaid, @Remarks, @InternalRemarks,
             @ExcludeInARAP, @CollectorID, @CardTypeID, @CardTerminalID, @External,
       @AccountOwner, @HMSDate, @HMSShiftID, @POSOID, @LoginName, GETDATE(), @LoginName, GETDATE(),
       0, @AutoGenerated,
       @GoldAdjustmentID, @Confidential, @EmployeeAdvance,
       1,
             @DeductedPPh, @ExSourceID, @ExSource, @WriteOffDepartment,
     @AccountIndex, @BIAssetID, @BIDriverID, @IsPanjarUJ, @BankCharges, @BankChargesAccountID, @BankChargesDepartment, @PIN, @SourceCashRefundID, @PPhTypeID, @EBankingMetadata, @FPNo, @BQID, @ProjectID,
             @Pending, @DeliveryOrderID, @KCPDeliveryOrderID, @FFBContractID, @SourceVoucherID, @IncentiveDetailID, @ExternalRef, @OtherOwnerCheck, @IsSODeposit, @TransferDate, @Jaminan, @WriteOffAccountID, @PVTax,
       @PVAmountTax, @ForexGainLossDepartment, @ForexGainLossAccountID, @IsPriviledge, @PriviledgeCardNumber, @PPhFormula, @CashFlowID, @PVSalesPersonID, @PalmContractID, @ExpMeterai, @CashRate, @PPhLocal, @IsAnonym, @AnonymName,
             0, @EDUHideDiscount, @EDUDiscReason, @BAccountType, @PPh23ID, @SettlementDescription, @AdvanceAccountID,
             @EDUReportDate, @DedOtobon,
             @City, @Branch, @Country, @IBANCode, @SwiftCode, @SortCode, @PendingCashID, @PendingCashAmount, @ChargeAmount,
             @BranchCode, @ABACode, @CorrBank, @CorrSwiftCode, @AllowOverBudget, @POTerm)
```

I changed this to look like the below:

```
INSERT INTO P_BS.dbo.FI_ARAP WITH (ROWLOCK) (Class,
                                             VoucherNo,
                                             VoucherCounter,
                                             VoucherDate,
                                             IsAR,
                                             IncomeOrExpense,
                                             AssociateID,
                                             AssociateName,
                                             CurrencyID,
                                             ExchangeRate,
                                             PaymentMethod,
                                             VoucherType,
                                             RecordedGuestID,
                                             IsFODeposit,
                                             ExpenseOrRevenueTypeID,
                                             ReservationID,
                                             CutFare,
                                             DontPostToGL,
                                             BankAccountID,
                                             CheckNo,
                                             CheckDueDate,
                                             ClearingID,
                                             BankName,
                                             CardHolderName,
                                             AccountNo,
                                             AmountPaid,
                                             Remarks,
                                             InternalRemarks,
                                             ExcludeInARAP,
                                             CollectorID,
                                             CardTypeID,
                                             CardTerminalID,
                                             [External],
                                             AccountOwner,
                                             HMSDate,
                                             HMSShiftID,
                                             POSOID,
                                             CreatedBy,
                                             CreateDate,
                                             LastModBy,
                                             LastMod,
                                             IncomingTransferVerified,
                                             AutoGenerated,
                                             GoldAdjustmentID,
                                             Confidential,
                                             EmployeeAdvance,
                                             Transferred,
                                             DeductedPPh,
                                             ExSourceID,
                                             ExSource,
                                             WriteOffDepartment,
                                             AccountIndex,
                                             BIAssetID,
                                             BIDriverID,
                                             IsPanjarUJ,
                                             BankCharges,
                                             BankChargesAccountID,
                                             BankChargesDepartment,
                                             PIN,
                                             SourceCashRefundID,
                                             PPhTypeID,
                                             EBankingMetadata,
                                             FPNo,
                                             BQID,
                                             ProjectID,
                                             Pending,
                                             DeliveryOrderID,
                                             KCPDeliveryOrderID,
                                             FFBContractID,
                                             SourceVoucherID,
                                             IncentiveDetailID,
                                             ExternalRef,
                                             OtherOwnerCheck,
                                             IsSODeposit,
                                             TransferDate,
                                             Jaminan,
                                             WriteOffAccountID,
                                             PVTax,
                                             PVAmountTax,
                                             ForexGainLossDepartment,
                                             ForexGainLossAccountID,
                                             IsPriviledge,
                                             PriviledgeCardNumber,
                                             PPhFormula,
                                             CashFlowID,
                                             PVSalesPersonID,
                                             PalmContractID,
                                             ExpMeterai,
                                             CashRate,
                                             PPhLocal,
                                             IsAnonym,
                                             AnonymName,
                                             RequireCheck,
                                             EDUHideDiscount,
                                             EDUDiscReason,
                                             BAccountType,
                                             PPh23ID,
                                             SettlementDescription,
                                             AdvanceAccountID,
                                             EDUReportDate,
                                             DedOtobon,
                                             City,
                                             Branch,
                                             Country,
                                             IBANCode,
                                             SwiftCode,
                                             SortCode,
                                             PendingCashID,
                                             PendingCashAmount,
                                             ChargeAmount,
                                             BranchCode,
                                             ABACode,
                                             CorrBank,
                                             CorrSwiftCode,
                                             AllowOverBudget,
                                             POTerm)
VALUES (@Class,
        @VoucherNo,
        @VoucherCounter,
        @VoucherDate,
        @IsAR,
        @IncomeOrExpense,
        @AssociateID,
        @AssociateName,
        @CurrencyID,
        @ExchangeRate,
        @PaymentMethod,
        @VoucherType,
        @RecordedGuestID,
        @IsFODeposit,
        @ExpenseOrRevenueTypeID,
        @ReservationID,
        @CutFare,
        @DontPostToGL,
        @BankAccountID,
        @CheckNo,
        @CheckDueDate,
        0,
        @BankName,
        @CardHolderName,
        @AccountNo,
        @AmountPaid,
        @Remarks,
        @InternalRemarks,
        @ExcludeInARAP,
        @CollectorID,
        @CardTypeID,
        @CardTerminalID,
        @External,
        @AccountOwner,
        @HMSDate,
        @HMSShiftID,
        @POSOID,
        @LoginName,
        GETDATE(),
        @LoginName,
        GETDATE(),
        0,
        @AutoGenerated,
        @GoldAdjustmentID,
        @Confidential,
        @EmployeeAdvance,
        1,
        @DeductedPPh,
        @ExSourceID,
        @ExSource,
        @WriteOffDepartment,
        @AccountIndex,
        @BIAssetID,
        @BIDriverID,
        @IsPanjarUJ,
        @BankCharges,
        @BankChargesAccountID,
        @BankChargesDepartment,
        @PIN,
        @SourceCashRefundID,
        @PPhTypeID,
        @EBankingMetadata,
        @FPNo,
        @BQID,
        @ProjectID,
        @Pending,
        @DeliveryOrderID,
        @KCPDeliveryOrderID,
        @FFBContractID,
        @SourceVoucherID,
        @IncentiveDetailID,
        @ExternalRef,
        @OtherOwnerCheck,
        @IsSODeposit,
        @TransferDate,
        @Jaminan,
        @WriteOffAccountID,
        @PVTax,
        @PVAmountTax,
        @ForexGainLossDepartment,
        @ForexGainLossAccountID,
        @IsPriviledge,
        @PriviledgeCardNumber,
        @PPhFormula,
        @CashFlowID,
        @PVSalesPersonID,
        @PalmContractID,
        @ExpMeterai,
        @CashRate,
        @PPhLocal,
        @IsAnonym,
        @AnonymName,
        0,
        @EDUHideDiscount,
        @EDUDiscReason,
        @BAccountType,
        @PPh23ID,
        @SettlementDescription,
        @AdvanceAccountID,
        @EDUReportDate,
        @DedOtobon,
        @City,
        @Branch,
        @Country,
        @IBANCode,
        @SwiftCode,
        @SortCode,
        @PendingCashID,
        @PendingCashAmount,
        @ChargeAmount,
        @BranchCode,
        @ABACode,
        @CorrBank,
        @CorrSwiftCode,
        @AllowOverBudget,
        @POTerm);
```

Although this is far taller, it's not an unreadable blob of text anymore; you can tell where the `INSERT` start, where the `VALUES` starts, and there's nothing "odd" inbetween. Yes, this ended up reflecting my preference, but it's not an eyesore for all the behold.

So, are edits that significantly change the writting preference of code a good edit? Personally, I don't think so, as they *force* that preference on the user, *however*, I do think that are "allowed" when the code itself needs formatting improvements overall. For example the changes I made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59615194/2029983) *(note I also think the latest edit is completely superflous on that post, but I am not rolling it back as it'll bump what is a very poor question in the end)*. Should someone reformat the code, based on their preference, when changing the rest of the question to be better formatted? My opinion is no, leave the code in their format, fix the other issues.

*Closing notes: This is not a call out the the person whom I just spoke in the comments about the edit, I am purely using the preference change as an example. I wouldn't have rolled back that edit had the underlying SQL not been changed; though I would not have agreed with the formatting changes. This is something I see more often and ignore, but now thought about if it is "right". This is purely a question of are code formatting changes, purely based on preference, good edits even if they do make significant changes to it but do not improve readability.*

Comment: Related: [When is it okay to edit answers for “Code Formatting?”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/263115/7795130) and [How far can I refactor the code in someone else's question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88627/363946)

Comment: That first one is actually quite probably a good duplicate candidate, @DavyM ; didn't find it when searching.

Comment: I would not call that change "reformat based on preference" - one line code is not formatted and not readable - so go ahead and format it to your liking.

Comment: I assume you're talking about the latter example, @AlexeiLevenkov ?

Comment: One thing I will point out is that while all four blocks of code require horizontal scrolling on my device (1080px wide) - the last one, while it does reduce the amount of horizontal scrolling, does result in what looks like, at a glance, loads of blank lines: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRRXo.png

Comment: That is, however, on a mobile device @WaiHaLee , and code isn't really written to be displayed well on a mobile device.

Comment: Your first example is stated as from a question. In that example the code is actually changed, not just the formatting. Changing the actual code in a question is something that should only be done *very* rarely, and only by someone who is an domain expert and who can verify that the change doesn't affect what's being asked about. I know you mention that you rolled it back for this reason, but the fact the example includes that change makes it a poor example. If you want to continue to use it as an example, it would be better to just remove the last 2 or 3 lines to eliminate that difference.